# Servlet retrieve data, construct JSP and send to Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I need to update a 'div' in my code with a form with the labels and inputs. The form was constructed in a JSP file, and I will fill this using the attributes received from my servlet.

I need get the attributes in the Servlet using my DAO object, send to a JSP page to construct the HTML code correctly, and so send this html code to my Ajax function, that will put the JSP code in my div.

But, when I do something like :

```
 request.setAttribute("user", user);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/user-list.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

I don't know how can I get this page code to send to my ajax function, because I have already called the dispatcher forward.

In my ajax function I am waiting the code to put in my div.

```
 $.get('../LoadPointServlet', function(responseText) { 
    $('#dataPoint').html(responseText);       
});
```

Comment: General approach seems fine. It is not clear what your exact issue is.

Comment: When I use getRequestDispatcher().forward() i will redirect to user-list.jsp. I need to update the form there with the attributes sended via setAttribute(), and so I need to put this code in a DIV on my main JSP page. I don't know how do this.

Comment: You need to better explain the flow of execution. When and where do you make the Ajax request.

Comment: Ajax Request to fill a div => Call a Servlet, that using a DAO, get the variables of my object => Send the variables to a JSP PAGE, that will construct my form with the variables => Send the CODE of JSP PAGE to my Ajax function, to insert in my DIV

Answer (score 0):

On your user-list.jsp page you can get the value of attribute "user" which you have put in Servlet by using:

```
request.getAttribute("user");
```

Set the updated values in user-list.jsp.

Comment: And how can I get the CODE of this page there and send to ajax?

Comment: the user-list.jsp page will return all the html content at runtime to your responseText variable.. just like in your code you have put that responseText into the element having id datapoint.